# Display only records exceeding four items

Tags: crystal-reports

My Group Footer shows the number of distinct items bought by each customer:

```
Cust Ref,      Items bought (distinct count)

001,            4
002,           12
003,           6 
004,           3
```

How can I display only the customers who have bought 5 or more distinct items?
I tried using  `distinctcount(items bought) > 4` but it looks at *all* the distinct items bought by everyone, not each individual customer. What formula should I use and where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place a group by CustRef, then at the footer place the CustRef and a formula named `@DistCnt` containing `(DistinctCount({ItemsBoughts}))` (It seems you've already done that)!

Then in the Section Expert section click on the (x-2) button near the suppress checkbox related to this group footer and write: `@DistCnt < 5` and save.

Answer (score 0):

Go to section Expert and then go to suppress write the below code and save

```
Cust ref <5
```